# How to save procedures address in array and then use them in Delphi

Tags: delphi, save, procedure, restore, memory-address

I have Tsqlquery which most fields use event Onchange. I need switch them off dinamically at runtime with out hard coding (for example Table.fieldbyname('ABC').Onchange:=Nil;) After that I need alse switch them on  (for example Table.fieldbyname('ABC').Onchange:=TableABCChange;) 
I did try to use Array of Pointers and use it like below:

```
var P:array [1..100] of Pointer;
begin
for i:=0 to Table.fields.count-1 do
 begin
    {save and switch them off} 
    P[i]:=@Table.fields[i].Onchange; 
    @Table.fields[i].Onchange:=Nil;
 end;
```

But I do not have idea how to switch them on

```
for i:=0 to Table.fields.count-1 do
 begin
    {restore and switch them on} 
    Table.fields[i].Onchange:=P[i]; <---- ERROR
 end;
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 9):

These event handlers are method pointers and so cannot be represented by a single pointer. They are actually represented by two pointers: one to the data (i.e. the object instance) and one to the code.

You are also accessing outside the array bounds. You defined an array with low index of `1` and promptly accessed index `0`. You also hard coded the upper bound of `100` which is somewhat risky. A dynamic array is what you need here.

Furthermore, by using `@` with the default compiler options that disable typed checked pointers, you are suppressing some of the compiler's ability to type check your code.

The `OnChange` event is actually a `TFieldNotifyEvent` method pointer. With that knowledge, your code should be written like so:

```
var 
  SavedChangeEvents: array of TFieldNotifyEvent;
....
// save and set event handler to nil
SetLength(SavedChangeEvents, Table.Fields.Count);
for i := 0 to Table.Fields.Count-1 do
begin
  SavedChangeEvents[i] := Table.Fields[i].OnChange; 
  Table.Fields[i].OnChange := nil;
end;
....
// restore
for i := 0 to Table.Fields.Count-1 do
begin
  Table.Fields[i].OnChange := SavedChangeEvents[i];
end;
```

Note that at no point do I use the `@` operator. Make it your goal never to use that operator with procedural types. Avoiding such use allows you to let the compiler check type safety. At the same time, enable [typed checked pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi)).

Comment: Yes you right. using the @ depend of compiler option I'm using lazarus and Fp (Free pascal option) . This was an mastake by usin wrong low index of array. This was just an example not part of real program. Easy way to show the problem. Any why Thank you very much. :))